# my chicken broth did not separate with layers

Tags: broth

I put frozen organic chicken bones that I have saved over the past year in a 6 quart crock pot, some bay leaves, pepper corns some celery, garlic and cooked everything on low for 24 hours.I let it cool but there was no layer of fat that came to surface. The liquid is still a creamy colored liquid 2 days later...is it supposed be cream colored???

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't roast the bones, then yes, it's going to be pale. Many recipes suggest browning the bones (I like to bake them at 450 for 45 minutes), for extra flavor and a nice color.

As for the lack of fat layer... the bones themselves don't have much fat. If you've got just cleaned bones, then I wouldn't expect a separate fat layer. If you'd included skin, then you'd expect it to have fat.

Either that, or your crock pot is broken, and it just sat there are room temperature for 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you cooked only bones, not sure there was enough fat to build up a layer...
On the chicken most fat is in the skin, the meat itself contains low fat and bones close to zero.